# When using bazel to build TensorFlow C++ call model, .so file doesn't work

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I want to use TensorFlow C++ api to call model and predict answers.
At fisrt, I clone the tensorflow repo

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Then I write the C++ code like below:

One code is a class to call TensorFlow api, the header file is like:

```
#ifndef _DEEPMODEL_H_
#define _DEEPMODEL_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

class DeepModel{
public:
    DeepModel(const string graph_path, const string checkpoint_path);
    virtual ~DeepModel();

    bool onInit();
    void unInit();
    vector<float> predict(vector<vector<float>>& x, string input_name, string output_name);
private:
    string graph_path;
    string checkpoint_path;
    MetaGraphDef graph_def;
    Session* my_sess;
};

#endif
```

After this, I write a simple encapsulation code. I want to compile a .so, and use the .so without tensorflow source code in the future. And my encapsulation code is like below:

```
#ifndef _MODEL_HELPER_H_
#define _MODEL_HELPER_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ModelHelper{
public:
    ModelHelper(const string graph_path, const string checkpoint_path);
    virtual ~ModelHelper();

    vector<float> predict(vector<vector<float> >& x, string input_name, string output_name);
private:
    string graph_path;
    string checkpoint_path;
};

#endif
```

I have write code to test above code, it works well. Then I want to compile .so using bazel.

My BUILD file is like below:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_binary")

tf_cc_binary(
    name = "my_helper.so",
    srcs = ["model_helper.cc", "model_helper.h", "deepmodel.cc", "deepmodel.h"],
    linkshared = 1,
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow"
        ],
)
```

then I rename model_helper.so to libmodel_helper.so, and write cpp code to test the .so file. And I want to compile the code, command is like this

```
g++ -std=c++11 test_so.cpp -L./ -lmy_helper -I./ -o my_helper
```

**Then I meet the error:**

```
.//libmy_helper.so: undefined reference to `stream_executor::cuda::ScopedActivateExecutorContext::~ScopedActivateExecutorContext()'
.//libmy_helper.so: undefined reference to `stream_executor::cuda::ScopedActivateExecutorContext::ScopedActivateExecutorContext(stream_executor::StreamExecutor*)'
.//libmy_helper.so: undefined reference to `tensorflow::DeviceName<Eigen::GpuDevice>::value[abi:cxx11]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I really don't know why. I can't use the .so alone?

Comment: When run ./configure in tensorflow repo, I don't set cuda option. Then the compile is ok. And It works well. What is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should reference libtensorflow_frameowork.so in your makefile. Just like code below:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test_so.cpp -L./ -lmy_helper -ltensorflow_framework -I./ -o my_helper
```

I guess bazel misses some source code in tensorflow into .so when compile my code.